# How to convert GroupingView to Grouping in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, ext.net

According to sencha in extjs 4 the remove GroupingView.

1. GroupingView has been removed and replaced with Grouping feauture.

But I want to change my old code accordingly and missing Listeners:

```
<ext:GroupingView ID="gridView" HideGroupedColumn="true" ForceFit="true" >
    <Listeners>
    <Refresh Handler="CheckHeader(#{checkSelectionModel});" />
    </Listeners>
        <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" />
</ext:GroupingView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be done this way.

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" ForceFit="true">
    <View>
        <ext:GridView runat="server">
            <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" />
            <Listeners>
                <Refresh Handler="CheckHeader(#{checkSelectionModel});" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:GridView>
    </View>
    <Features>
        <ext:Grouping runat="server" HideGroupedHeader="true" />
    </Features>
</ext:GridPanel>
```